# how to start running cron jobs from php code?

Tags: php, cron

I used below code to update my cron job list:

```
    $output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
    echo $output;

    file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $output.'* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /home/myjob.php'.PHP_EOL);
    echo exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt');
```

I suppose echo exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt'); will start running all cron jobs, but it didn't. I also substituted exec by shell_exec, but it sill didn't start the cron jobs.

How can I let the cron jobs START RUNNING by using php?

Thanks.

Comment: `cron` is a system that schedules a scripts execution. If you need to execute the script, just use the command directly in the `exec` function.

Comment: I bet you lack privileges. Note that exec runs command using specific user. You can check user by exec('whoami')

Comment: Thank you both. exec('whoami') will give me the correct user as when I created my cron jobs manually. Apparently, echo exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt'); can only update the cron job list, but not run the jobs!!! I'll need to go to my webmin panel and click 'run' and then the cron jobs will start working.

Comment: yes that is correct.. as BotskoNet mentioned, cron doesn't execute the scripts; it's just a list of commands and when they should be run. The system itself then reads through the crontab executes them at the specified times. So if you want to actually run them, you will need to run the commands yourself.  You can do this by getting the list from crontab like you did, then looping through them and running them through `exec()` - though this may or may not work, depending on permissions apache has vs. the command being run..